# Will WPF Ribbon work on a machine with no office?

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

I've been looking on the site http://wpf.codeplex.com/ and found the Ribbon control finding my needs.
I was wondering if it requires any Office licence things etc. on the machine, or this just needs the toolkit dll.

Does it require Win-7 or is compatible on XP machine as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ribbon doesn't have any dependency on office, it just renders with that style.  You're all set with or without office.

As for the other question, it depends on a framework up to the WPF level being installed, whatever OS that is, including XP.  Pretty soon, you'll want that to be WPF4 due to the much better font rendering IMO.